# Generate temporary email addresses and read emails - NodeJS

Tags: node.js, api, email

I want to create a NodeJS program, which can verify an account with an temporary email.

The program will generate random email address and get the message body from it, then this will run and again and change the email address again, and it will go on like that.
Just like temp-mail.org, 10minutemail etc.

So far I have found these:

1. [TempMailGen](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tempmailgen)
2. [Mailtrap.io](https://mailtrap.io)

Is there a way to implement these in my NodeJS program?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the node module for temp email. Here, Node wrapper for creating and fetching temporary, disposable emails, as well as their new messages.

**Installation**

run `npm install node-temp-mail` or `npm i node-temp-mail`

**Usage**

```
var TempMail = require('node-temp-mail');

// Let's create an address object so it can be accessed by the module.
var address = new TempMail("testAddress");

// We already have the address object, so now let's access it and get a list of the emails in a nice & neat json object.
address.fetchEmails(function(err,body){
  console.log(body);
});

// If for any reason you need to see the full temporary email address, you can use the following function.
address.getAddress()
```

Comment: how to create the test address?

Answer (score 1):

You can use **Gmail**.

Google allows to append `+<number>` to your ID and send emails to the same inbox as the actual email address.

For example, if your email address is jhondoe@gmail.com, then you can send an email to

- jhondoe+1@gmail.com
- jhondoe+2@gmail.com
- jhondoe+3@gmail.com
- .
- .
- .
- chhavigupta+n@gmail.com

All the emails will be sent to the jhondoe@gmail.com inbox.

Now, you may be concerned about disposing of the test emails.

Well, for that you can set a filter in your gmail to send those test emails to your Trash folder. Google automatically deletes all emails older than 30 days. This much time would be sufficient for you to verify that the emails were actually delivered and have the correct information and format.

Comment: is there a limit for n?

Comment: That i'm not sure of. You will need to try it out and check.

Comment: The `+` is just a separater. You can have any combination of allowable email address letters, e.g. jhondoe+project-123-test-49@gmail.com